# Benefits of registering copyright - Should I register or not?

Tags: copyright, canada, copyright-notice

I have a question regarding copyright registration in Canada. From what I read, it is not mandatory to register copyright in Canada. But at the same time, some folks suggest you should register your work as soon as you release it. Do you have any idea about whether I should register it or not?

What are the benefits?

Comment: I found this link on the net with general explanation: https://www.pellonia.io/post/how-to-register-your-copyright-in-canada

Answer (score 10):

Registering your copyright provides official proof of ownership, see [Copyright Act, §53ff](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/c-42/page-16.html). It is not mandatory since you can use other means to argue that you own the copyright, but in case you want to sue someone for infringement, it simplifies what you would have to do. Unlike the US, it is not required in order to file an infringement lawsuit.

Comment: You don't need to register your copyright in the US to file an infringement lawsuit - it just leads to higher potential damages if you do